# Lisp dfs not returning acyclic path

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am creating a lisp program to find an acyclic path in an undirected graph, and return that path to the user. The path does not necessarily need to be the shortest path.
My full code is the following:

```
(defvar graph '((A B C)
                  (B A C)
                  (C A B D)
                  (D C)
                  ))

(defun getneighbours (graph node) ;Gets neighbors of the given node.
    (if (assoc node graph)
        (cdr (assoc node graph))
        '()
    )
)

(defun acyclicpath (graph start goal) 
    (setq visited '()) ;Reset the returnpath and visited variables for the next search.
    (setq returnpath '())
    (if (dfswithpath graph start goal) ;Path found reverse path and return.
        (reverse 'returnpath)
    )
    nil
)

(defun dfswithpath (graph node goal)
    (if (equal node goal) ;Goal reached return true.
        (push node returnpath)
        t
    )

    (push node visited) ;Update visited list.

    (dolist (neighbour (getneighbours graph node)) ;Call dfs on each neighbour of node if not already visited.
        (if (not (member neighbour visited))
            (if (dfswithpath graph neighbour goal)
                (push node returnpath)
                t
            )
        )
    )
    nil ;No path found
)

(print (acyclicpath graph 'A 'C))
```

Running this code results in a nil value being returned always by the dfswithpath function. I have narrowed down the issue to recursive dfswithpath call in the dolist function. It appears that it never resolves to t, and so the nested push function never gets called. However, I cannot figure out why this is the case.

Comment: The function in question returns `nil` because the last form in that function's body is `nil`.

Comment: I personally didn't "get" Lisp at all until I quit using the "I'm used to block-structured curly-brace languages" layout. Lisp is not "Java with slightly different punctuation" but an entirely different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dfswithpath` function returns nil because the last form in that function is `nil`.   To return from a function other than via executing through to the last from, you must use `(return-from dfswithpath <value>)`.

Stylistically, that should only be used when there is no nice way to write the function in a functional style.

```lisp
(defun dfswithpath (graph node goal)
    (if (equal node goal) ;Goal reached return true.
        (push node returnpath)
        t
    )
```

Are you expecting this to return `t` from the function? It does not. You need that `return-from`, or to rearrange the code to make it unnecessary.

Moreover, `if` takes single expressions as arguments, to the `t` is in the "else" position: `(if condition this else)`.

```lisp
    (dolist (neighbour (getneighbours graph node)) ;Call dfs on each neighbour of node if not already visited.
        (if (not (member neighbour visited))
            (if (dfswithpath graph neighbour goal)
                (push node returnpath)
                t
            )
        )
    )
    nil ;No path found
```

Inside `dolist`, you can use `(return <value>)` to terminate the `dolist` form, with that value. If it terminates naturally, it will return `nil`. So you can do this at the end of your function:

```
(dolist (neighbour ...)
  (if condition
    (return t))
  ...))
```

And that's it; no `nil` is required afterward. The last form of the function is the `dolist`, which yields `nil` if it executes all the iterations. (There is a place in the `dolist` syntax to specify an expression, the *return-form*, whose value gives `dolist`'s return value, but we don't need that here).

Comment: This basically solved it thank you! I misunderstood the if statement to be more like it was in java, where I can add multiple statements within the if statement.

Comment: @Pandasonsleds Right. For that, *cond* is used. Historically *cond* came before *if*; John MacCarthy invented *if* as a shorthand. However, historically, *cond* clauses did not have multiple forms: they were strictly pairs! In Common Lisp, *cond* clauses can have zero (!) or more forms in addition to the test form itself. `(cond ((> x 3) (do this) (do that)) ((< x 0)) (t 42))`.  If `x` is greater than `3`,`(do this)` and `(do that)` are exuted, yielding the value of `(do that)`. Otherwise if `x` is less than zero, `T` is returned (the value of that form itself). Otherwise `42` is returned.

Comment: Idea: posting your working function (or any other code) on the Code Review stackexchange, to get feedback on how it can be improved.